# Best method of getting a tooltip to appear around an image?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I've been looking at some jQuery plugins to show a tooltip around an image when it's hovered on. But I haven't been able to find one, what I was looking for was a tooltip to load and with the description, text, and rating while using the same image inside the tooltip.

So I was thinking about making my own, and wanted to know what you guys think of the best way of doing this?

The General idea is top have a row of images and when a user hovers one, a rounded retangle appears with the same image inside and it populate the information to the left of the image. And they have to leave the tooltip for it fade away, not the thumbnail.

And do you guys know of any jQuery tooltip plugins that do this? No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumbail">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="hiddentooltipinfo">
        <div class="tooltipinfo">
            <div class="info">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>

            <div class="rating">
                <p>85%</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be something along these lines? http://jsfiddle.net/BFzE7/

Comment: Just about. Lemme look into to closer with some customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **I haven't found a tooltip plugin *that I like.***  I'd just build one yourself.  I'd be willing to help, to be honest.
- I'd recommend that you **use the html `img` attributes** and put the rating as a decimal value or a percent with the % sign. Both clearly indicate percentages.  Also, be sure to **include `width` and `height` attributes**.
- **The plugin that I've disliked the least would be [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)**.

---

```
<!-- You could use this as your markup: -->
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumbail">
        <img src='' width='' height='' title='' alt='' data-rating='' />
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Depending on why you have the extra markup, you could potentially
     Just use the following: -->
<img src='' width='' height='' title='' alt='' data-rating='' />
```

Comment: Hey Levi, I would be storing more information I just didn't write it out. Like **views**, **date added** and etc

Essentially it's a rounded div with all the content hidden, but the image. And everything will appear once you hover over the image. And everything will hide once you leave the tooltip, not the image.

Comment: @Bombcode If each one of those fields is short, then I'd still recommend sticking them in as `data-*` attributes and using some sweet jQuery to pick them out and display them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ALT and TITLE properties on the image tag, if you want more jquery has plugins and such for cool tooltips..

```
<img src="#" alt="Submit" title="submit">
```

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: Um, what? I don't you get what I mean. I'm looking for the best way to do this or if a tooltip with similar functionality already exist.